# Wordpress Max Users vs. SQL Login

Tags: sql, wordpress

I'm working on a Wordpress site that will require users to login and register some information in addition to basic stuff in order to see data and make a purchase... but they'll likely never come back, or less than 5 times.

I started by using the Wordpress login and register for users, but I'm concerned about user load. We're looking at potentially 500+ users registering per day. I've seen reports Wordpress can handle it, but I'm wondering if it's too much.

Think it's better to go with a flat MySQL and just create my own login on top of Wordpress for purchasers only? Or stick with Wordpress? What's the maximum load Wordpress can handle on users?

Comment: I really think it depends more on your host than on Wordpress

Comment: Wordpress, when configured correctly, if very powerful and can take that sort of strain.

However, you might need to think about separating your "application" server from your "database" server. (I.E have a dedicated MySQL server, and a dedicated application server)

Comment: I do like the separate db idea... I'll probably end up going with a separate database outside of the Wordpress users, if only because they won't really be logging in on a frequent basis, probably only once. Seems like Wordpress might be overkill in that situation.